# Analyzers for projects what are building for .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have project which targets just .Net 4.0. I also heard about that new Roslyn compiler arrived with Visual Studio 2015, and it provides new analyzer feature.Can I write analyzers for projects what are building for .Net 4.0 using Roslyn compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Roslyn analyzer only reads the source code, not .NET Framework version.